# Elasticsearch write throughput issues

Tags: elasticsearch

Having an awfully hard time getting Elasticsearch to keep bulk indexing throughput up. At this point I am trying to max out my target box (24 cores, 64GB RAM, ES has 32GB heap allocated, mmap storage for my target index, refresh interval set to -1). I am using the BulkProcessor API to parallelize the write. I am testing with a static JSON document ~2KB.

No matter what I do on sharding (5, 8, 10 -- no difference), or on setBulkSize, setFlushInterval, setConcurrentRequests, throughput stalls after 60,000 documents. I increased the bulk queue size to 1000, and as I monitor /_cat/thread_pool, I see 24 bulk.active (my core count) and bulk.queue hovering around 210. But my box has tons of capacity to spare -- heap usage stays around 5% and RAM usage at 25%. Disk, CPU and network are essentially idle on the target box.

Can anyone suggest possible causes and corrective measures? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also in one of many tests, I set the refresh rate to -1. Now I see lots of bulk activity going on (both the client spinning through a bulk insert loop and the server showing bulk threads busy), but I see zero documents in the index. Can this be related? I see no growth in the data files for the index.

Comment: Also, the size of the thread pool seems to have no effect. I doubled it to 48 but other than bulk.active going to 48 nothing seems to change